# Visual Studio - Add a button/checkbox to a toolbar to switch the readonly file property,

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I've been trying to add a button/checkbox to my Visual Studio IDE (2005) so I can change the read-only property for a file without having to go to Windows Explorer and change it there.

We sometimes do that a lot in my team.

Does anyone of you have something like this? a Macro would just do fine for me. I want to speed up this task.

Please let me know if you know of something I can use.

Thanks!

Comment: "We sometimes do that a lot in my team" >> Why? Are you breaking around read only attributes of your version control system? Then I suppose you should change your workflow.

Comment: not really "breaking around", but we "implement" the other SE code in our environment during code-review to make sure it works as intended. And since the file is actually locked by that SE, we need to remove the read-only attrib.

Comment: If I understand that correctly, you do a checkout of somebody else's code to do the review? Why don't you do that in a separate folder? Anyway, the copy would be the explorer's task, not the one of Visual Studio. Can you please explain your workflow a bit more in detail?

Answer (score 0):

If you just need to update read-only files from Visual Studio, you should be able to change your environment preferences to "Allow editing of read-only files; warn when attempt to save".

The following link describes:
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/zainnab/archive/2010/09/15/edit-read-only-files-vstipedit0074.aspx

Comment: Well, the only problem with this is that as soon as I try to edit a read-only (non-checked-out) file, the version control app pops up a check-out dialog. We could instruct the pop-up dialog not to appear, but it's important it does appear (so we check-out every file we are to modify). See my comment above for why we must work with locked files. The only way we've found to work around this is by manually removing the read-only attrib. Thanks for the responses!